# Word Combination question

Tags: phrases

Certain words are often used in a fixed combination. As an example consider the phrase - '*hardly......when*' as used in the sentence - "*Hardly* had I entered the room *when* the light went out."  For clarity consider another example - "*No sooner* did the teacher go out *than* the pupils started playing."

What should be the combination for -
1) *Rarely...*
2) *Never before...*

Also, can anyone provide me any links where I can find more of such combinations?

Comment: These are all **[Negative](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf)** constructions, and negatives always have [strange grammar](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf), often retaining fixed phrases with archaic syntax, while also arising naturally in slang and new constructions. Sort of a "Poet's Corner" in the language.

Comment: What Prof Lawler has explained has been covered before, several times in fact, a couple times by none other than himself. See the question this has been closed as a duplicate of, and follow the trail of related questions linked from there if you wish. Other than the inversion, there is nothing the examples you provided require, i.e. there is no word that *must* appear later on in a sentence starting with "Rarely...".